# aritsan crontab job generate many progcess

Tags: php, laravel, command, cron, laravel-artisan

I use aritsan command(lavaral 5.1) deal background job,

I set * * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 in crontab accordance with the mamul.

and my job setting like

```
'$schedule->command('job')->cron('0 * * * *');'
```

in Kernel.php

This task works well, but when I check my server process a few hours later, I find aritsan generate many process,

Note: In my job, I write `exit()` after program end in `handle()` method.
please help me find that why artisan generate those progcess(not exit?), it occupy many memory.

Thanks very much!

```
~ ps -aux|grep artisan|grep -v grep|wc -l  
24  

root     15690  0.0  2.3 235588 11872 ?        S    Nov16   0:05 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     16382  0.0  2.3 237748 11996 ?        S    Nov16   0:06 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     17735  0.0  2.3 237748 12036 ?        S    Nov16   0:05 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     17786  0.0  2.4 237748 12052 ?        S    Nov14   0:15 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     20274  0.0  2.4 237748 12056 ?        S    Nov14   0:14 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     23771  0.0  2.4 237748 12056 ?        S    Nov14   0:12 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     24191  0.0  2.4 237748 12056 ?        S    Nov16   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     26192  0.0  2.4 237748 12048 ?        S    Nov16   0:02 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
root     26287  0.0  2.4 237748 12048 ?        S    Nov14   0:12 /usr/local/bin/php artisan job  
....
```

Comment: There should be no need to add `exit` to the `fire` or `handle` methods of a Job.. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: @Luceos if i don't set exit in handle methods,It may lead to this questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try executing the scheduled tasks manually with

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

and see how much time it takes to run.If this takes a lot of time it means that you have a bottleneck somewhere and it never reaches your exit().
You might have a racing condition in there with more than one processes requesting for the same thing.You would need to find the time consuming task and try to optimize it.Also you might want to use

```
->withoutOverlapping();
```

so that no more than one task is running simultaneously.

Comment: thank you ,my friend.I checked my program,it may curl timeout leaded to this question,I set lower curl timeout,this question no longer happen.

Comment: You are more than welcome. You could also accept the answer.